# mizzao:sharejs-codemirror is not working in meteor

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, sharejs

I added mizza:sharejs-codemirror in meteor but it is giving error "cannot access sharejs without intialijation"[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvUGB.png) 
and the html code is:

```html
<head>
 <title>textcircle</title>
</head>

<body>
 <h1>Welcome to TextCircle</h1>
 {{>editor}}
</body>

<template name="editor">
 {{>sharejsCM docid=docid id="editor"}}
</template>
```

and this is the js file:

```html
Documents=new Mongo.Collection("documents");
if (Meteor.isClient){
console.log(Meteor);
Template.editor.helpers({
 docid:function() {
  return Documents.findOne()._id;
 }
});
}

if (Meteor.isServer){
 Meteor.startup(function(){
  // code to run on server at startup
  console.log("helo");
  if(Documents.findOne()){
    Documents.insert({title:"my new document"});
}
 })
}
```

Comment: Where do you initialize sharejs?

Comment: According to me it is not initialized and this package is simply added by using command 'meteor add mizzao:sharejs-codemirror'.

Comment: So does it work when you initialize it before loading the Template?

Comment: It is not working at all